# Proof of Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality in probability form

Tags: probability, inequality, expected-value, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

In my university course, we were given the following proof of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality:
[image]

My issue is with the last line, surely we get that:

$$|E(XY)| \leq \sqrt{E(X^2)E(Y^2)}$$
but it is not true in general that $E(|XY|)\leq |E(XY)|$

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: may I know the book with its title and author?

Comment: where that inequality (XY <= 1/2(X^2+Y^2))came from?

Comment: How can we assume that $E(Y^2) \neq 0$ WLOG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result follows from the fact that X and Y are assumed to be non-negative, as stated in the first line.

Answer (score 3):

Simply apply what you have proved with $X,Y$ replaced by $|X|,|Y|$.